# Not able to send the mdm Payload and Command to device

Tags: python, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am developing mdm for iOS for testing purpose. I have installed the profile on the device and I have got the Device Token, PushMagic and now I want to send the mdm payload ￼`{"mdm":"PushMagicValue"}`

and for this I am using the code

```
from APNSWrapper import *

wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('PushCert.pem', False)
message = APNSNotification()
message.token('CgeMZKRl2cqZAmGQ0VNCvySXAsaMPqeHga9ZUC3kqpM=')
message.appendProperty(APNSProperty('mdm', 'D60DAB80-A41D-4689-9F14-004E29431742'))
wrapper.append(message)
wrapper.notify()
print 'Done'
```

The problem is that my test server sends this message without any errors but I am not able to see any response on my device logs. Please tell me where I am wrong and how to make it work Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple now sends the Device Token in base64 encoded format for this we have to use the base64 function with the device token
instead of `message.token('CgeMZKRl2cqZAmGQ0VNCvySXAsaMPqeHga9ZUC3kqpM=')`

I used

```
message.tokenBase64("6CORK2VBuJCPi1Y8oB3PRyoIiSf7Aq5sD7noZ/Awxao=")
```

and this did the trick ....